# How to download file into webserver using only angular frontend?

Tags: c#, angular, file, upload

I have a frontend website made using `Angular` that accepts an uploaded file. I want to be able to save this file into the web server the website is being hosted on. I would prefer to only use `Angular` to do this, but I can also accept if there is a  way to do it in `ASP.Net Web API` backend.

Answer (score 0):

You can download the webserver file using angular.

Try the below example...

```
 downloadFile() {
    window.open("http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf") //your URL
  }
```

Comment: I want to download a file that the user uploads into the webserver